# How to put headings into classes on HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
div.countries {
  color: blue;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="countries">
  <h2>Mexico</h2>

</div>

<div class="countries">
  <h3>Brasil</h3>

</div>
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with the code above in CSS. In the HTML section the headings are written as:

```
<h2>
Mexico
</h2>
```

and

```
<h3>
Brasil
</h3>
```

But the h2 and h3 still won't appear as blue or in Arial as I want them to. I can't see what's wrong but I am pretty much a complete amateur at this and just trying to learn. Hope someone can help me :) If you want to to specify anything else or need more information, please ask.

Comment: I pasted the code from your question into a stack snippet and it looks like it's working fine. Make sure your question has a [mcve]. You probably have other CSS rules that are overriding the ones you posted here.

Comment: Works if you run the snippet.

Comment: If you're using an external stylesheet, are you sure it's loaded? In Chrome: view your source, click on the stylesheet path, if it's a 404, somethings not right.

Comment: What do you see in the style inspector?

Answer (score 2):

It works fine, most likely something overrides them, you could try to impact deeper and maybe it will override them back:

```
div.countries>h2, div.countries>h3 {
  color: blue;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h2, h3 {
   color: blue;
   font-family: Arial;
}
```